# Нужен совет по PHP и MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть БД приблизительно на миллион записей у которой 4 поля: name, summ, original, original_already. Изначально первые три поля заполнены, нужно написать максимально оптимальный по времени/памяти запрос, который будет обновлять четвертое поле. Для каждой записи original_already должен равняться 1, если хотя бы в одной записи БД, у которой совпадают значения name и summ с текущей, значение original=1. В противном случае, в поле должен быть записан 0.

"Лобовое" решение (два вложенных цикла) не пройдет по времени. Хочется, чтобы запрос/скрипт работал не более часа и загружал не более 512M.

Comment: Толи вечер то ли хз что, но я не смог осилить вопрос. Как то более попроще можно его расписать ?

если в базе кроме текущей есть еще одна запись с таким же name и summ то нужно проставить original_already = 1 ?

или как ?


Блин ну это талант нужен что бы так написать! Раз 10 прочитал, все равно не до конца понял что нужно

Comment: Если у нее (второй записи) original=1, то и первой и второй записи нужно присвоить original_already 1, иначе 0.

Comment: Общая задача такова. В БД хранится, куда (5 поле в БД, но оно тут не играт роли) человек (который характеризуется name и summ) подал документы, и подал ли он оригинал документа. Нужно, если он куда-нибудь его (оригинал) подал, во всех остальных записях (с такими же name и summ) записать, что оригинал он уже подал (поле original_already = 1). Надеюсь хоть как-то объяснил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение на php не подойдет - все решается SQL - запросами.
Например, так:

Запрос 1:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
    SELECT DISTINCT name, summ FROM table WHERE original=1
)
```

Запрос 2:

```sql
UPDATE table SET original=1 WHERE (name,sum) IN (SELECT name,sum FROM tmp)
```

Comment: я думал сделать так. Только одна проблема. На маленькой БД (в 100 записей я проверил, работает отлично). Вопрос в том, как, запустив запрос, узнать о состоянии его работы (сможет ли он завершиться через пол часа или будет выполнятся целый день)?

Comment: Честно говоря, не думаю, что время работы запроса будет превышать несколько минут. Но если берут такие сомнения - ну, простейший логгер напишите, пусть кинет в файл время работы скрипта. А вообще я бы для начала попробовала запустить скрипт вручную - через браузер и оценить

Answer (score 0):

Всё что я понял, у вас не правильно построена бд, вам куда проще в одной таблице хранить только людей, в другой то куда они приходили и с какими документами. Если бы вы сделали так, то таких проблем бы не возникло. Так что крайне рекомендую переделать пока вы не столкнулись с более трудными проблемами.

А вообще я бы вам посоветовал бы что то типа такого

```
<?php
$res = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT name, sum  FROM table WHERE original = 1');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET original = 1 WHERE name ='".$row['name']."' and sum = ".$row['sum']);
}   
?>
```

PS в коде могут быть ошибки так как негде было проверить

Comment: Возможно, БД у меня и построена не правильно, но сделать ее так, как сказали Вы, у меня не получилось чисто по техническим причинам (время на обновление будет очень большим). А еще, вы представляете себе сколько будет выполнятся тот код, который вы написали? Ваш код сделает приблизительно 100000 запросов к БД размером в 1000000 записей:) И такой код мне нужно каждый день запускать...

Answer (score 0):

В T-SQL я бы написал так

```sql
update [table]
set original = t2.original
from [table]
    join [table] t2 on t2.name=[table].name and t2.[summ]=[table].summ and t2.original=1
```

Предлагаю также поиграться с индексами. Ну, и базу надо по возможности нормализовать.